# setApiVersion(‘\xE2\x80\x982\xE2\x80\x99’) error

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

Installed twitteroauth-6.1.0. with composer.

I have a twitter script to upload images.

twitter2.php::

```
$connection->setApiVersion(‘2’);
```

Config.php:

```
private const SUPPORTED_VERSIONS = [‘1.1’,‘2’]; (line 15)
```

```
  public function setApiVersion(string $apiVersion): void {

        if (in_array($apiVersion, self::SUPPORTED_VERSIONS, true)) {
            $this->apiVersion = $apiVersion;
        } else {
            throw new TwitterOAuthException('Unsupported API version'); (line 58)
        }
    }
```

Outputs this error from Config.php.

Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Config->setApiVersion(‘\xE2\x80\x982\xE2\x80\x99’) Config.php on line 58

I was expecting the number 2 instead of this. Any idea why?

I searched everywhere, and can not find an answer.

Thanks!
Robert

Comment: Are those wicked quotes `‘1.1’,‘2’` in your original code? If so, change them to regular ones (`\xE2\x80\x98` is a "_left single quotation mark_", `\xE2\x80\x99` a "_right single quotation mark_")

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   I set it for 2. It returns a new error:  Undefined constant 'xE2\x80\x982\xE2\x80\x99'  .

Comment: What text editor are you using? Stop using it. It's clearly not meant for writing code because it won't stop using quotes that aren't actual quotes.

Comment: Why is it being returned in bytes?

Comment: Does it need decoding?

Comment: brombeer Good catch. I used my keyboard single quotes and it resolved that issue. :)